# Population pyramid Tornado chart with slicer for year - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to build a population pyramid chart with custom visual Tornado chart. The population pyramid has data for 5 periods (2016, 2021, 2026, 2031, 2036). Once I built the pyramid I used a custom slicer "Play Axis" dynamic slicer.  All good so far but by default the population pyramid is showing the total for all the 5 periods and when I use the Play Axis slicer it moves through each time period but at the end it comes back to the total of 5 periods.

I am wondering if it is possible to show the default view as 2016 in the chart and slicer rather than the total.  Please see the screenshot and I have also included the example Power BI file for your reference.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AubIV2PXG9p4gqo-jw3-DqUYuGORGA?e=9am2Uu

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Pop pyramid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create these following 3 measures-

```
erp_lowest_year = 

VAR min_year = MINX(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[Year])

RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sheet1[ERP]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(Sheet1,Sheet1[LGA],Sheet1[Agegroup],Sheet1[Sex]),
        Sheet1[Year] = min_year
    )
)
```

```
erp_sum = SUM(Sheet1[ERP])
```

```
erp_final = 
SWITCH(
    SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Year]),
    BLANK(), [erp_lowest_year],
    [erp_sum]
)
```

Now, configure your **Tornado** chart as below-

[image]

This should work for you. You can also Download the updated report from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10yxVnF9u-sQTv8EfSUWPkNjjOzMl2iPO/view?usp=sharing).